# Difference between File and Path of java.net.URL

Tags: java, url

What is the diffecence between getFile() and getPath() of java.net.URL oject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

> public String getFile()
>
> Gets the file name of this URL. The returned file portion will be the same as getPath(), plus the concatenation of the value of getQuery(), if any. If there is no query portion, this method and getPath() will return identical results.

so getPath() might be

```
/path/file.php
```

and the getFile() might be

```
/path/file.php?query=hello
```

Answer (score -1):

`getFile()` will return the name of the file:

```
MyFile.txt
```

`getPath()` returns the path to the file:

```
C:/MyFolder/MyFile.txt
```

Comment: That's not what the Javadoc suggests.

Comment: @PeterLawrey 
getFile()
Gets the file name of this URL.
getPath()
Gets the path part of this URL.
That is the JavaDoc, so afaik, yes, it does

Comment: @Stultuske Then check Peters answer. Or this code example: `URL u = new URL("http", "blub.com", 123, "test/sub/blub.txt?opt=1"); System.out.println(u.getFile()); System.out.println(u.getPath());`. Even if you use `u = new File("blub.txt").toURL()` you would get that result.